# Trying to redirect to different page based on login credential provided in DJango

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to redirect to different pages based on the login credentials in django.

For an example: There are two login provided

If i login with X credentials then i will be redirected to X page. While on **same** login page if i login with Y credential i will be redirected to correponding Y page.

I tried to put condition in user_login views.py file but this gives me following error.

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'companyDashboard.html' not found. 'companyDashboard.html' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

My views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import RequestContext
from wfhApp.forms import UserForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required



# Create your views here.

@login_required
def company_dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'wfhApp/company_dashboard.html')



@login_required
def companyDashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'wfhApp/companyDashboard.html')



@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))



def user_login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username= username, password=password)

        if user:

            if user.is_active:

                if user.username == 'prashant':
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('company_dashboard.html'))

                elif user.username == 'saurabh':
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('companyDashboard.html'))

                else:
                    return HttpResponse("Account Not Exists")

            else:
                return HttpResponse("Account Not Active")

        else:
            print("Someone tried to login and failed")
            print("Username: {} and Password: {}".format(username, password))
            return HttpResponse("Invalid Login Details")

    else:
        return render(request, 'wfhApp/login.html')
```

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: The **`reverse()`** function takes the ***name of the URL***, not the *name of template file*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [urlresolvers docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/), to use `reverse` you must set **name** in path (urls.py). Don´t add `.html` extension, use the setted name at `urls.py`.

```
from news import views

path('archive/', views.archive, name='news-archive')
```

Use the setted name.

```
# using the named URL
reverse('news-archive')

# passing a callable object
# (This is discouraged because you can't reverse namespaced views this way.)
from news import views
reverse(views.archive)
```